# Twitter Search API query results don't match keyword

Tags: python, api, search, twitter, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy Cursor to find some tweets.

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='pg&e', count=100, lang='en', since=sinceDate, until=untilDate).items():
    print str(tweet.created_at) + '\t' + str(tweet.text)
```

I have noticed that the tweet.text for many of the tweets returned mention "pg", as in the movie ranking, but don't contain my query, "pg&e" at all.

Why is this?  Is there a way to get an exact match?  Also, is there a way to give tweepy.Cursor a list of keywords to search for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`q="\"pg&e\""` will give you what you want. I guess the `&` is interpreted as an AND by the API, so you have to specify that you want to search for pure text by putting extra quotation marks.

If you want to search for more keywords, using OR in your query should work, provided the query does not get rejected for being too complex. Something like `q="\"pg&e\" OR other_keyword OR \"exact expression to search\""` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you!  Would you mind explaining what is going on with the quotes and slashes in q="\"pg&e\"" ?

Comment: Well, you want to search for the exact string `"pg&e"` (note the quotation marks), and not simply `pg&e`. Since you want to put quotation marks in a string, you have to escape them, hence the slashes. Without escaping, `q=""pg&e""` results in a syntax error. Another solution would have been to change the quotation marks used: with `q='"pg&e"'` instead of `q="\"pg&e\""`, the result is the exact same.